# Cordova (w. Visual Studio, Genymotion), FileTransfer always gives error code 3

Tags: php, android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, genymotion

I've been struggling for over a week with this task for work, and hoped other points of view might help me overcome this issue.  My goal here is to overcome the dreaded FileTransfer: 3 error and successfully upload a file.

### **Situation**

I've been tasked with creating a basic Android application that records audio, and uploads it to a given address.  I'm running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, with Cordova Tools 2, and testing on Genymotion (Android emulator) and WAMPServer (PHP server to receive the uploaded file).

All Cordova dependencies are properly installed.  Genymotion is tested and fully functional.  My project builds correctly.

Here's my code:

### **Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Recording App</title>

<!-- CordovaTest references -->
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

    // A button will call this function
    function captureAudio() {
        // Launch device audio recording application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 1 audio clips simulataneously.
        navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 1 });
    }

    // Uploads files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile)
    {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        var fileURI = mediaFile.fullPath;

        var serverUri = encodeURI("http://192.168.0.110/uploadRecording.php");
        options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // Suggested fix for failure to resolve path.
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.headers = {Connection: "close"};

        showAlert(mediaFile.fullPath);
        //showAlert(options.fileName);
        //showAlert(serverUri);

        checkConnection();

        ft.upload(
            fileURI,
            serverUri,
            function (result) {
                showAlert("Recording uploaded to " + serverUri);
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function (error) {
                showAlert("Could not resolve " + serverUri + ': ' + error.code);
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            options,
            true);
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert(message) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            message,            // message
            alertDismissed,     // callback
            'Alert',            // title
            'Ok'                // buttonName
        );
    }

    // Called when capture operation is finished
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    function captureError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Audio Capture Application</p>

<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="captureAudio();">Record Audio</a>

<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myapp9612dd" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>RecorderApp</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="192.168.0.110" subdomains="true" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800" />
  </platform>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" version="1.0.1" />
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="False" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="False" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="1.1.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.0.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.3.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="3.0.0" />
</widget>
```

### **uploadRecording.php**

```
<?php

# Receiver for uploaded audio recordings

echo "I'm here";

#if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
#{
    $targetDir = "uploads";
    $targetFile = $targetDir . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    createOutputDir($targetDir);

    echo "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    if(isValid($targetFile) == true)
    {
        uploadFile($targetFile);
    }
#}

# 
function uploadFile($targetFile)
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

# 
function createOutputDir($targetDir)
{
    if(!file_exists($targetDir)) 
    {
        if(!mkdir($targetDir)) {
            die("failed to create save folder $targetDir");
        }
    }
}

# 
function isValid($targetFile)
{

    if (file_exists($targetFile)) 
    {
        echo "This file has already been submitted.";
        return false;
    }

    if (! isValidExt($targetFile)) {
        return false;
    }

    # If we made it this far...
    return true;
}

#  
function isValidExt($targetFile)
{
    # Android recording formats
    #  High quality recording = m4a (Windows Phone / Android / Apple)
    #  Normal quality recording = amr (Android)
    $allowedFileTypes = ["m4a", "amr"];

    # Restrict file formats
    $uploadFileType = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($uploadFileType, $allowedFileTypes) == false) 
    {
        echo "This service is for audio recordings only.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

?>
```

And here's what I've already tried to fix the issue (thanks to StackOverflow and others):

- Set chunked mode to false (some server compatibility issues)
- Set "Connection: Close" to FileTransfer headers.
- Upgraded File and FileTransfer plugins (remove and then re-add them
  in config.xml).  Some versions of FileTransfer had this issue as a
  reported bug.
- Tested upload destination address can be reached by loading it in
  chrome.
- Access permissions to the destination address have been set in
  config.xml
- Completely cleaned and rebuilt project.
- Tested destination folder is created and can be accessed.
- Tested GenyMotion emulator has internet access.
- Howled in frustration (remarkably ineffective).
- Tested destination address, file name, and file address are properly
  set in code (although File:/ only has one slash, I don't know if that
  could be an issue).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for taking the time to read all this.